# How to join 2 tables without value duplication in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, join

I am joining two tables using:

```
select table1.date, table1.item, table1.qty, table2.anotherQty 
from table1
INNER JOIN table2
on table1.date = table2.date
```

**table1**

```
date   | item   | qty
july1  | itemA  | 20
july1  | itemB  | 30
july2  | itemA  | 20
```

**table2**

```
date   | anotherQty
july1  | 200
july2  | 300
```

Expected result should be:

```
date   | item  | qty | anotherQty
july1  | itemA | 20  | 200
july1  | itemB | 30  | null or 0
july2  | itemA | 20  | 300
```

So that when i sum(anotherQty) it will have 500 only, instead of:

```
date   | item  | qty | anotherQty
july1  | itemA | 20  | 200
july1  | itemB | 30  | 200
july2  | itemA | 20  | 300
```

That is 200+200+300 = 700

Comment: Really the best thing to do here would be to just sum `anotherQty` in its original table, before you do the join.

Comment: The only correlation between the two tables is the date column. So why would you expect "200" to appear on the row with "itemA"? Why not "itemB", or any other "july1" record?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, but know that so long as the qty values differ across rows, that you're going to still get the 'anotherQty' field breaking out into distinct values:

```
select 
    table1.date, 
    table1.item, 
    table1.qty, 
    SUM(table2.anotherQty)
from table1
INNER JOIN table2
    on table1.date = table2.date
GROUP BY
    table1.item, 
    table1.qty,
    table1.date
```

If you need it to always aggregate down to a single line per item/date, then you will need to add a `SUM()` to table1.qty as well. Alternately, you could run a common table expression (`WITH()` statement) for each quantity that you want, summing them within the common table expression, and then rejoining the expressions to your final SELECT statement.

**Edit:**

Based on the comment from @Juan Carlos Oropeza, I'm not sure that there is a way to get the summed value of 500 while including `table1.date` in your query, because you will have to group the output by date which will cause the aggregation to split into distinct lines. The following query will get you the sum of anotherQty, at the sacrifice of displaying date:

```
select  
    table1.item, 
    SUM(table1.qty), 
    SUM(table2.anotherQty)
from table1
INNER JOIN table2
    on table1.date = table2.date
GROUP BY
    table1.item
```

If you need date to persist, you can get the sum to show up by using a WINDOW function, but note that this is essentially doing a running sum, and may throw off any subsequent summation you're doing on this query's output in terms of post-processing:

```
select  
    table1.item,
    table1.date,
    SUM(table1.qty), 
    SUM(table2.anotherQty) OVER (Partition By table1.item) 
from table1
INNER JOIN table2
    on table1.date = table2.date
GROUP BY
    table1.item,
    table1.date,
    table2.anotherQty
```

Comment: You get the same result OP doesnt want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/beeef/1

Comment: Ah, yeah it's because of the date column. I'm not sure that there is a way to get this to work if the OP wants to include date, other than to use a window function which may throw off how they need to consume the data.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/beeef/7)**

```
WITH T1 as (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "date" ORDER BY "item") as rn
  FROM Table1
), T2 as (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "date" ORDER BY "anotherQty") as rn
  FROM Table2
)
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1."date" = t2."date"
      AND t1.rn = t2.rn
```

**OUTPUT**

Filter the columns you want, and change the order if need it.

```
|  date |  item | qty | rn |   date | anotherQty |     rn |
|-------|-------|-----|----|--------|------------|--------|
| july1 | itemA |  20 |  1 |  july1 |        200 |      1 |
| july1 | itemB |  30 |  2 | (null) |     (null) | (null) |
| july2 | itemA |  20 |  1 |  july2 |        300 |      1 |
```